# How to solve error during include of component in Adobe Experience Manager?

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I am using Adobe Experience Manager with Eclipse, I've followed the instructions given in this tutorial
https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/component-basics.html.

Everything was running fine. However, If I add a hello world component it gives me an error of:

**Error during include of component '/apps/wknd/components/content/helloworld'**

> **Error Message:**
>
> org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Cannot get DefaultSlingScript:
>   Compilation errors in
>   org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/apps/wknd/components/content/helloworld/helloworld_html.java:
>   Line 52, column 2348 :
>   com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd.core.models.HelloWorldModel cannot be
>   resolved to a type

**Processing Info:**

> Page  =   /content/wknd/us/en/component-basics     Resource
>   Path  =   /content/wknd/us/en/component-basics/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/helloworld_1476106194
>   Cell  =   helloworld   Cell Search
>   Path  =   page|basicpage/root|responsivegrid/responsivegrid/helloworld
>   Component Path    =   /apps/wknd/components/content/helloworld

**Full Exception**

> org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Cannot get DefaultSlingScript: Compilation errors in
>   org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/apps/wknd/components/content/helloworld/helloworld_html.java:
>   Line 52, column 2348 :
>   com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd.core.models.HelloWorldModel cannot be
>   resolved to a type    at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:510)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:192)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:278)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:373)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.page.PageLockFilter.doFilter(PageLockFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:437)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(AssetContentDispositionFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:372)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.aem.professional.core.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.servlets.CoreFormHandlingServlet.doFilter(CoreFormHandlingServlet.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:244)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:86)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.doFilter(RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher$1.doFilter(Dispatcher.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager.invokePreprocessors(WhiteboardManager.java:1012)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) Caused by:
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Compilation
>   errors in
>   org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/apps/wknd/components/content/helloworld/helloworld_html.java:
>   Line 52, column 2348 :
>   com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd.core.models.HelloWorldModel cannot be
>   resolved to a type    at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.compiled.SlingHTLMasterCompiler.compileSource(SlingHTLMasterCompiler.java:429)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.compiled.SlingHTLMasterCompiler.compileHTLScript(SlingHTLMasterCompiler.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.compile(SightlyScriptEngine.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:379)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491)

Any idea on how to solve this kind of issue or any other references about AEM Errors? Thank you!

Comment: Kindly include the full stack trace. This error generally occurs when the class/model is not available in AEM i.e., your bundle is not installed / active or if the class didn't get registered as a Sling Model or if there was an exception thrown by the class during execution.

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks! @rakhi4110

Comment: is your bundle active in OSGi?

Comment: @rakhi4110 It's not active, only installed was displayed. How to activate this one?

Comment: Click on the bundle name and it should expand. In case some dependencies are missing it would highlight those classes in red. In case everything looks normal, click on the start icon towards it's right and monitor the logs. It should generally give a stacktrace of what went wrong when activating the bundle.

Comment: @rakhi4110 Nothing happens if I click the play icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting your bundle in OSGi and install it again. Go to your core directory and run this command:

```
mvn -PautoInstallBundle clean install
```

Comment: Could you also explain what the problem is and why this helps?

Comment: According to op, the bundle is installed but cannot be activated. I suspect something went wrong during installation.

Comment: How I can delete the bundle in OSGi?

Comment: There's a delete button at the right end of each bundle entry in the Felix console

Answer (score 3):

This can occur because of two reason.
1) You didnt build the core module or your core bundle is not getting built properly. Use the command `mvn clean install -PautoInstallBundle` to build only the bundle.

2) Second reason might be your bundle is getting built and deployed on the server but the dependency is not getting resolved. Check in the system console if the bundle is active. If its not active then expand the bundle and check which dependency is missing. Once you find the missing dependency, then install the dependency in the  osgi.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this packages under build tag of core/pom.xml:

```
                    <configuration>
                        <bnd><![CDATA[ Import-Package: 
                          javax.annotation;version=0.0.0, \
                            com.day.cq.wcm.api;version=0.0.0, \
                            org.apache.sling.api.resource;version=0.0.0,\
                            org.apache.sling.api.servlets;version=0.0.0,\
                            *]]>
                        </bnd>
                    </configuration>
```

It worked for me!